# Cannot restore a database with SSMS 2017 over MSSQL vNext Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: vagrant, ssms, ubuntu-16.04, database-restore, sql-server-vnext

I've just installed the last version of **Sql Server Management Studio 2017** (v17.0) in order to connect to the brand new **SQL SERVER vNEXT** on **Ubuntu 16.04**.

So, I tried to restore the classic **NORTHWND** database, just to test the environment, but the system returned an error.

Although I was using **sa** login the system gave to me an **access permission error** to the folder `/var/opt/mssql/data/` (where the **.bak** file reside).

The error message was:
`Cannot access the specified path or file on the server. Verify that you have the necessary security privileges and that the path or file exists.`

I've already check the access of that folder, and it is set correctly to the user **mssql**, infact if I use **SSMS 2014**, with the same login, I can restore that database without any problem.

I'm wondering if it isn't a **bug** of **SSMS 2017** after all.

Btw, my configuration is:

*the server:*

- Ubuntu 16.04 virtualized with Vagrant + VirtuaBox
- Sql Server vNext

*the client:*

- Windows 7 SP1
- SSMS 2017 (v17.0 build 14.0.17099.0) (doesn't work)
- SSMS 2014 (it works!)

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems still not possible restore a database through the UI. But, partially using the UI, I taken in place this old fashioned workaround:

- Open SSMS 2017 and connect to the database
- Open a New Query window
- Before to procede locate your `.bak` file into the machine
- Run this command to get the list of **database and log files** from your `.bak`
  file, in my env was: `RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/Northwind.bak'`
- Write down the database name, database filename, log filename and their logical names for using in the next step
- Run this command to restore the database 
  `RESTORE DATABASE NORTHWND
  FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/Northwind.bak'
  WITH MOVE 'Northwind' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/NORTHWND.mdf',
  MOVE 'Northwind_Log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/NORTHWND_Log.ldf'
  GO`
- Et voilà, the database was successfully restored!
- So, be sure to use the right names before running the `RESTORE DATABASE`.

I keep deeping to find the right solution, for the moment this is enough for me.